# Do java programs execute in different platforms with the same speed?

Tags: java

Let's consider a scenario and say there are two OS'es, windows and Linux. I have written a program and compiled it and a class file is generated and I've used it to execute in both Windows and Linux.

My question is:

- Would the speed taken to execute the same class file differ in both the os'es(Assume we have the same hardware specs)?

we all know that JVM itself needs to be implemented on each platform separately so the code which passes each instruction from JVM to the processor differs for each OS JVM is built for,right? So, if we consider small programs the execution speed might not vary much but:

- What about programs with thousands of lines of code?
- Is there any recommended OS JVM works fastest on?
- If there is no difference in execution speed,then how's that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible to get Java programs to run faster by compiling the bytecode into an executable; the disadvantage is that such executables will only work on the platform in which it is created.

Comment: JRockit is high performing JVM... https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/overview/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes Linux is faster than windows, sometimes not.

From kernel point of view, **Linux kernel is faster than Windows**, because:

Linux kernel is big kernel, it includes everything you knows as an OS,the drivers, the file system, the memory management, the task scheduler, everything is in the same kernel space, communication between them is easy and low cost.
But Windows NT kernel is micro kernel, it only includes basic functions the OS need, other functions are not int the same kernel space, they need IPC(inter-process communication) to talk to each other, this is quite expensive compared to Linux kernel.
**Windows is faster than Linux, when it comes to some GUI things**, e.g. games.

Because the design of the X window system of Linux is aimed to be flexible, thus it lost some performance. Good news is the Wayland project is now improving this situation.

Comment: sorry,this is irrelevant to what i asked!

Answer (score 1):

The JVM for a given OS must be able to run Java bytecode according to the JVM spec as well as implement the standard Java library. It follows that if there are differences in JVM performance from one OS to another, those differences would arise from differences in how the JVM and/or the standard class library are implemented. Places where that could occur might be graphics handling, asynchronous I/O, etc.

1. The line count doesn't mean anything.
2. Not that I know of, but it depends on the program
3. If there is no difference in speed, the program's hot spots are not making many system calls.

If your code is mostly crunching numbers, for example, then it should not have a performance disparity across operating systems.